# Expo network response timeout? Port issue

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting error on my expo go app.

Error :

Uncaught error:java.net.SocketTimeout Exception: failed to connect to /192.168.100.10(port 19000) from / 192.168.100.2(port 39440) after 10000ms.

[image]

Comment: can you show me error image?????

Comment: image added @ThắngTrươngKhắc in question

Answer (score 3):

**Connecting Expo Go from device (android) and my react-native app (windows 10):**

Some reasons I found:

1. Different internet network
2. IP address wrong (one possible reason: virtual machines)
3. Firewall

Some facts:

1. About change LAN connection to TUNNEL in Metro UI:

- Metro bundler user interface is not displayed in browser (only a json) because it was released after expo-cli@5.5.1.206
- Change type connection is not recommended. It is slower.
- settings.json file in .expo folder has "hostType": "lan" attribute but it has not be changed manually. There is the documentation about "to enable tunneling" (when it is really necessary) https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/?redirected

2. You could set your IP address as an enviroment variable and run npm start. CyrisXD explains here https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app/issues/144

**My solution:**

- Windows settings / To allow app (Node.js Javascript Runtime) to communicate through Windows firewall[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Gpo.png) / Advanced security / Entry rules[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE856.png).
- *Spanish*: Configuración de Windows / Permitir a las aplicaciones comunicarse a través de Firewall de Windows Defender[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Gpo.png) / Cambiar configuración / Reglas de entrada[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE856.png).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following step by step:

Is their computer IP address in the URL correct?

Do you have a firewall that could be blocking the connection?

Or could your router be blocking the connection?

Can you get it working with expo start --tunnel?

right click connection internet icon Bottom right=> change adapter options=> right click  your internet=> right-click => propertis =>tab sharing => allow other network.....

[image]
[image]

Comment: is their any reset default setting? Everything was working fine and suddenly got this error

Comment: last step instructions are unclear. couldn't find tab sharing allow other network

Comment: i am using wifi. Ethernet is not available

Comment: You use the wifi for your phone to be the same as the wifi that the laptop is sharing with your phone

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows 10 :
1- Select the buttonStart > Settings> Update & Security> Windows Security then Firewall & network protection
2- deactivate the Firewall for public network

Comment: This is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

For Windows change the firewall settings and allow Node.js JavaScript Runtime to access private networks.

Search for **Windows Defender Firewall** > Click **Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall** > Search for **Node.js JavaScript Runtime** > Click **Change Settings** > Check for **private** networks

Answer (score -1):

Turning off firewall should work.
In my case,It was **McAfee**